# how to display an image that is outside of public_html in yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

My problem is that I try to show an image located outside the public_html folder of my project, for this, in the view I call a controller method in Yii, running the following command:

```
public function actionImagenreadfile2($file) {

    if(file_exists($file)){
        header('Content-Type: '. FileHelper::getMimeType($file));
        ob_clean();
        readfile($file);
    }
}
```

The way I call this controller from the view is the following:

```
<img src="<?php Yii::$app->runAction('ficha/imagenreadfile2', ['file' => $imagen]); ?>">
```

Where $imagen is the image path, but at the time when the display image is displayed as text/plan.

Comment: You can refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105185/yii-2-upload-document-outside-public-folder/38107705#38107705 It is similar need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix your view :

```
<img src="<?= Url::to(['ficha/imagenreadfile2', 'file' => $imagen]); ?>">
```

You could also use [`yii\web\Response::sendFile()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#sendFile()-detail) in your controller :

```
return \Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);
```

Read more about [sending file with Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-responses.html#sending-files).

And the most important, you should check `$file` since your action is completely unsecured...

Comment: check $file how?