# Yii2 - Where can I store common resources

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Now I am using `Yii2 - Advanced` version for developing my application. In that application, some data like images is adding from the `backend` area. Here I need to access those data from the `frontend` also. So I need to keep those data in a common shared sector. I know there is a `common` directory in between `backend` and `frontend` where we can place the common configurations, models, etc. My question is whether I can store my shared resources in that common folder or in any other manner.

Any help will be appreciated. Please help

Comment: What kind of resources do you want to share between frontend/backend?

Comment: I want to share images/documents, uploading from backend to both frontend and backend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload files in root folder in yii2 advanced template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493615/how-to-upload-files-in-root-folder-in-yii2-advanced-template)

Answer (score 2):

To share uploaded files a solution is to create a new folder `upload`(don't forget to set the right permissions) in the app-root. All other kind of files(code, config, views, assets) i would put in to `common`.

Think about creating a alias like `@upload` to access the folder easily (see [bootrap.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/config/bootstrap.php)):

```
Yii::setAlias('@upload', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/upload');
```

Comment: Is it the better solution in this case ?

Comment: In my opinion the upload folder doesn't fit in common folder, also because the folder needs special permissions.

Comment: On Github someone made a improved version of the advanced template and he did it like i suggested it here: https://github.com/nenad-zivkovic/yii2-advanced-template

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define if the image you want to access it directly using url or not. If you want to access it directly. create a folder "uploads" inside "web" folder.

If not you can follow this answer about how to access files from outside public folders: [Yii 2. Upload document outside public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105185/yii-2-upload-document-outside-public-folder)